# Apache Kerberos auth prompts user for password

Tags: active-directory, apache-2.4, kerberos

I am trying to setup single-sign on against our Active Directory server for my Apache using the `mod_auth_kerb` module.

I have the following configuration in Apache:

```
AuthType      Kerberos
AuthName      "Test"
KrbAuthRealms COMPANY.LOCAL
Krb5Keytab    /etc/apache2/http.keytab
```

The keytab was created with the following command:

```
ktpass -out http.keytab \
       -princ HTTP/myserver.company.local@COMPANY.LOCAL \
       -pass <REDACTED> \
       -mapuser COMPANY\myserver-HTTP \
       -crypto AES256-SHA1 \
       -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL
```

I have verified that the principal in the keytab is also added to the account name.

I have another server with similar configuration where it works; the users are authenticated without a password prompt.

Any ideas on how to further troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Any usefull logs ?

Comment: An output from `ktpass` could also be useful. What are Windows domain level and kvno value? Can you provide us the contents of krb5.conf file? What OS is your Apache httpd running on?

Comment: what encryption type mod_auth_kerb supports? Instead of restricting to only one type, can you include more/all encryption types in "crypto" option? Also if you run ktpass in AD domain you shouldn't have to put domain qualifier in "mapuser" parameter - however I can't say that including doamain will definitely cause problem.

Comment: @strongline This use of `-mapuser` is perfectly valid and works for me. And for the `-crypto`-part - it's worth to try with a weak *RC4-HMAC-NT* and try to upgrade to the strongest, correctly working one.

Comment: Are the permissions correct when you've moved the file to your linux box? Also do the KVNO's match? I had problems where they weren't matched and it wouldn't login but would with a manual u/p entry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `KrbMethodK5Passwd off` in your apache conf file